# Selected value not displayed on AngularJS Select

Tags: angularjs

My problem is when i change the value of the dropdown menu the value isn't displayed in the dropdown menu but the correct value is displayed in my console. Not sure why it isn't working at the moment because i have a same implementation of this in another project. Maybe i'm overlooking things.

> On initialization i set

```
selected_type = types[0]
// What will result in Type1 being displayed on page load.
```

> Fiddle you can find here: https://jsfiddle.net/596tzsh8/7/

Comment: the `Id` property is your value, so `selected_type = types[0].Id` should work

Comment: You should change the `ng-options` to this: `ng-options="type as type.Name for type in types track by type.Id"` because your `ng-model` is the type itself, not the Id. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/596tzsh8/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ng-options="selected_type as selected_type.Name for selected_type in types track by selected_type.Id"
//                 ^
//         the object itself
```

... instead of:

```
ng-options="selected_type.Id as selected_type.Name for selected_type in types track by selected_type.Id"
//                  ^
//            the object's ID
```

Then, in your callback function, replace:

```
var typeID = this.selected_type;
//                      ^
//              the object itself
```

... by:

```
var typeID = this.selected_type.Id;
//                        ^
//                 the object's ID
```

... and you're all set!

See your forked JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/94s8v2k3/), or play around with the snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["controllers"])

var controllers = angular.module("controllers",[]);
controllers.controller('myController', function($scope){

 $scope.types = [{
            Id: 1,
            Name: 'Type1'
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            Name: 'Type2'
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            Name: 'Type3'
  }];

  $scope.GetValueTypeDropdown = function () {
   var typeID = this.selected_type.Id;
     $scope.the_type = $.grep($scope.types, function (selected_type){
       return selected_type.Id == typeID;
      })[0].Name;
      console.log($scope.the_type);
    return $scope.the_type;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <form>
          <select name="type" class="col-xs-12 dropdown-list"
                  ng-model="selected_type" class="col-xs-8"
                  ng-init="selected_type = types[0]"
                  ng-options="selected_type as selected_type.Name for   selected_type in types track by selected_type.Id"
                  ng-change="GetValueTypeDropdown()">
          </select>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Already had a feeling it wasn't that hard, but just couldn't find the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the select as follows,

```
<select name="type" class="col-xs-12 dropdown-list" ng-model="selected_type" class="col-xs-8" ng-init="selected_type = types[0]" ng-options="type as type.Name for type in types track by type.Id" ng-change="GetValueTypeDropdown()">
```

also you can have a $scope variable and display it on ng-change

```
$scope.GetValueTypeDropdown = function() {
 console.log($scope.selected);
};
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jj936L6v/)**